# Firebase transaction completes with null value and no errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-realtime-database, transactions

The question is somewhat similar to [Firebase transaction returns null and completes without error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50124612/firebase-transaction-returns-null-and-completes-without-error) . However, I already had the suggested solution.

The following uses Firebase web version 9. Running in node v14.17.3

```
const returnVal = await runTransaction(firebaseRef, async node => {
  console.log("1", node);
  if (node && node.ready != true) {
    node.ready = true;
  }
  console.log("2", node);
  return node;
});
if (!returnVal.committed) throw new Error("Not committed");
console.log("3", returnVal.snapshot.toJSON());
```

Before you go ahead and say, I am not setting node as an empty object, I expect it to become an object later on already.

And here is my output.

```
1 null
2 null
1 {otherMeta: {…}}
2 {otherMeta: {…}, ready: true}
3 null
```

As you can see, the transaction is completed with a null value. Which is strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: just remove the `async` keyword.

Frank nailed it on the head, but I'm going to write down a separate answer so that I can use syntax highlighting. If you have two identical functions:

```
function theAnswer() { return 42; }
async function theEventualAnswer() { return 42; }
```

These two functions behave very differently. The first one returns the literal `42`. The second one actually returns `Promise.resolve(42)`. If you try to add `theAnswer() + 1` you get `43`. If you try to add `theEventualAnswer() + 1` you get `'[object Promise]1'`.

In this case, you've returned `Promise.resolve({...node, ready: true})`, which the SDK later [tries to turn into a Reference](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/database/src/core/Repo.ts#L964) and gets some pretty weird results because it expects concrete types.

I've filed [a bug](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5526) on your behalf that details how the team could have provided you with a compile-time error message.

Comment: You're the one who caught the superfluous `async` keyword. I'm just the loquacious one who pulled this into a whole answer and bug report.

Comment: I will mark this as the answer for the weary travelers that walk on by.
I still think async is a better approach for the callback, where the promise can be resolved for a commit, and rejected for cancelling the transaction, instead of having to return an undefined.

Answer (score 3):

I was about to file a regression bug against the SDK, when I noticed that this seems to come from the `async` keyword.

If I use this code:

```
runTransaction(firebaseRef, async (node) => {
  console.log("1", node);
  if (node && node.ready != true) {
    node.ready = true;
  }
  console.log("2", node);
  return node;
}).then((result) => {
  if (!result.committed) throw new Error("Not committed");
  console.log("3", result.snapshot.toJSON());
});
```

I get the output for the last log as:

> 3 null

When I remove **only** the `async` keyword (which is not needed anyway), I get:

> 3 {a: true, ready: true}

My test bed: https://stackblitz.com/edit/firebase-v9-rtdb

I have no what about the `async` keyword could be causing it. Although as said the keyword is unnecessary in my snippet, it's needed in your code and I don't see how it would affect the result.

Comment: I had a requirement of an async callback, and it makes more sense to have the transaction run async, where the promise can either be rejected or resolved to commit or fail a transaction. Anyways, looks like I will have to find a workaround. Thanks!